# Plotting mass spectra with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spectra

I need some help figuring out what's wrong with my mass spectra plots and I have a couple problems:
1) I want the plots to show a full peak for the mass spectra measured (beginning at 0.0) but my plots seem to show a gap from the first point to the last leaving a weird looking peak. [image: floating mass spectra peaks I get in my code]
[image: What my advisor would like these peaks to look like]
2) I want to plot all the data together like my advisor did in his plot, but my data appears to break up. And one of my files will not plot with the others even though it plots well on it's own. [image: weird broken plotted peaks]

I've written a function to read the data from the data files, and the function is simply just a reader, and doesn't do any of the plotting itself. I used Matplotlib to plot these spectra. Any advice?

Comment: Ok, you're describing what the plots you made lack in your eyes, but it would be equal important to know how they were created. To help you, you would please have to add 1) the structure of your data (a few sample lines perhaps, as text in your post, not as Image links) 2) the code how you were trying to read in the data 3) the code how you were trying to create the plots

Comment: I suspect that the"missing" x,y values have y=0, which then becomes a NaN when you log-transform the data. NaNs are ignored in plotting with matplotlib. We would need to see the whole data files to check, though.